# Delphi XE3 160bit public (open) source hash algorithm

Tags: delphi, hash

I just received some new security directives regarding our applications database stored passwords.
We´ll have to implement 160 bit hash to encrypt the stored passwords.
The original string should not be obtained from the crypted string (same as MD5) and we have to use a public algorithm.

I was searching for Delphi´s implementation of MD6, but after a long search googlin it, I gave up.

Any tips ?

Thanx !

Comment: If you MUST use SHA-1 which I would not (there is a free 190GB, 15-billion-entry lookup table online) then at least add SALT and rounds of hashing. You should do this anyway.

Comment: I've got a few here: http://yoy.be/item.asp?i3010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our Open Source [SynCrypto](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SynCrypto.pas) unit features SHA-1 and SHA-256 hashing.

They are optimized for speed (with tuned x86 assembler), and work from Delphi 5 up to XE6, for Win32 to Win64.

For cross-platform, you can use our other Open Source [SynCrossPlatformCrypto](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/CrossPlatform/SynCrossPlatformCrypto.pas) unit, which targets all platforms, and features SHA-256, so is OK for your requirements.

If you can, use SHA-256 and not SHA-1. SHA-256 is enough for [NSA Secret encryption](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/programs/suiteb_cryptography/). :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to generate 160 bit hash string you would have to use SHA-1 hashing algorithm.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1

But since you are already be going on implementing new hashing algorithm I suggest you implement one of SHA-2 hashing algorithms instead. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2
Why? So you won't need to be updating the hasging algorithms any time soon as SHA-1 is already quite old (a bit younger than MD5).